# Regex to capture 15 Jun 1985

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to catch all dates with the form 15 Jun 1985.

I'm using a regex which is obviously wrong, but not sure what the problem is.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
re.findall("\b\d{1,2}\s\D+\s([2][0]\d\d|[1][9]\d\d)\b"
```

My logic:

```
\b | starts the expression
d{1,2} | 1 or 2 digits
\s | space
\D+ | any non digit character, no limit
\s | space
([2][0]\d\d|[1][9]\d\d) | the year 19xx or 20xx
\b | end boundary
```

Comment: Try `re.findall(r"\b\d{1,2}\s+(?:Jan|Feb|Ma[ry]|Apr|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sept?|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(?:20|19)\d\d\b", s, re.I)`

Comment: `re.findall(r'(\d+) (\w+) (\d+)', 'Today is 15 Jun 1985, I think')`

Comment: What do you mean with obviously wrong?  It [matches](https://regex101.com/r/uXptVa/1) 15 Jun 1985.

Comment: for some odd reason it doesn't work for me.  Getting an empty output.  Would love to know what I was doing wrong.  Both solutions above worked for me. @Thefourthbird

Comment: try regex101.com

Comment: You are using [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and in your regex you have a capturing group `()`. You could make that a non capturing group `(?:)`. [Demo](http://rextester.com/BKAI43436)

Comment: many thanks for this.  I accepted the answer for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches but you are using [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

*From the docs*

If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups

So that would give you `1985`

What you could do it make your capturing group a non capturing group and write it a bit more compact:

[`\b\d{1,2}\s\D+\s(?:20|19)\d\d\b`](https://regex101.com/r/jK0ola/1)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FEVILS39227)

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
import re
s = "I'm trying to catch all dates with the form 15 Jun 1985."
print(re.findall(r"\b\d{1,2}\s[A-Za-z]+\s\d{4}\b", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['15 Jun 1985']
```

Comment: doesn't the w+ allow digits into the middle term, where I only want text?

Comment: In that case you can use `print(re.findall(r"\b\d{1,2}\s[A-Za-z]+\s\d{4}\b", s))`